# SOAP request does not call correct method

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm doing a soap request against this https://www.openxades.org:8443/?wsdl

For that I generate a valid soap envelope can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/UhsJC8Yf) and this envelope requests correct data with this utility http://soapclient.com/SoapMsg.html

But when I request it from java like this

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            String url = "http://www.sk.ee/DigiDocService/DigiDocService_2_3.wsdl";
//when I replace it with this https://www.openxades.org:9443/DigiDocService I get message send failed, and different error codes.

            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(req.getBytes());
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(null, is);
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

            String serverURI = "https://www.openxades.org:9443/DigiDocService";

            // SOAP Envelope
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("", serverURI);
            MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "");
            soapMessage.saveChanges();
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);
```

I get the generic wsdl file not the method call. I've tried different combinations of URLs, generate java classes from wsdl file and so on... still could not get it to work. Any ideas?

## EDIT

If someone should come here with a similar problem then these were the commands to add the certificate. InstallCert.java can be easily found from google.

java InstallCert [host]:[port]

keytool -exportcert -alias [host_from_installcert_output] -keystore jssecacerts -storepass ["changeit" is default] -file [host].cer

keytool -importcert -alias [host] -keystore [path to system keystore] -storepass [your_keystore_password] -file [host].cer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, try

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, serverURI);
```

instead of

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);
```

because at the moment that call is going to the url of this WSDL.

Make sure your XML is correct. To test I just added a method to return some XML. The example code below works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SOAPException {

    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory
            .newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory
            .createConnection();

    String url = "http://www.sk.ee/DigiDocService/DigiDocService_2_3.wsdl";
    // when I replace it with this
    // https://www.openxades.org:9443/DigiDocService I get message send
    // failed, and different error codes.

    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(getXmlString().getBytes());
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(null, is);
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "https://www.openxades.org:9443/DigiDocService";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("", serverURI);
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "");
    soapMessage.saveChanges();
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, serverURI);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    soapResponse.writeTo(out);
    String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());

    System.out.println(strMsg);

}

static String getXmlString() {
    return "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""
            + " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""
            + " xmlns:dig=\"http://www.sk.ee/DigiDocService/DigiDocService_2_3.wsdl\">"
            + "<soapenv:Header/>"
            + "<soapenv:Body>"
            + " <dig:CloseSession soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"> "
            + "<Sesscode xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">?</Sesscode>"
            + "</dig:CloseSession>"
            + "</soapenv:Body>"
            + "</soapenv:Envelope>";

}
```

Comment: when I change it I get message send failed and some error codes (google do not know what they mean).

Comment: For example Error code 10048 or 9548, but the text message is always message send failed.

Comment: When I copy the code you provided I still get `HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed`

Comment: Got it working now, there were some certificate issues, SOAP request was correct. Thanks!